# Compare results with percentage with PRINT

Tags: t-sql

I've queried the results I'm looking for, now I simply want to compare "OnTime" Y/N for a percentage "OnTime", but I'm having trouble comparing the alias and/or using the column name in the PRINT function.  Any suggestions?

```
SELECT
shmast.fcnumber AS Customer,
shmast.fcbcompany AS Company,
somast.fsono AS SalesOrder,
somast.fduedate AS DueDate, 
shmast.fshipno AS Shipper, 
shmast.fshipdate AS ShipDate,
--DATEDIFF(DAY,somast.fduedate,shmast.fshipdate) AS 'Days',
CASE
    WHEN shmast.fshipdate <= somast.fduedate THEN 'Y'
    WHEN shmast.fshipdate > somast.fduedate THEN 'N'
END AS OnTime
FROM somast
JOIN shmast ON somast.fsono = shmast.fcsono
WHERE shmast.fcnumber = '000111'
PRINT (OnTime = 'Y') / COUNT (*)
/*GROUP BY
shmast.fcnumber,
shmast.fcbcompany,
somast.fsono,
somast.fduedate, 
shmast.fshipno, 
shmast.fshipdate*/
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: I do not undestand, What is **OnTime**? Why do you try to print while executing a query? Do you know how works the print command? Please try to explain a little more so we can help.

Comment: The title of this question is incorrect, you should edit this question, post an example, add the database type that are you using and you must explain a little better that is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving it another shot after your description

```
SELECT
sum(CASE WHEN shmast.fshipdate<=somast.fduedate THEN 100.0 END)/count(*) AS OnTime
FROM somast
JOIN shmast ON somast.fsono = shmast.fcsono
WHERE shmast.fcnumber = '000111'
```

Comment: This is a slightly different approach, but I'm certainly open to exploring it.  What this change is doing is only comparing one row at a time, "if this order shipped on time (shipdate<=duedate) then give it 100 and divide by the count of that record."  What I'm hoping to do is compare the results of the entire query with the same CASE (shipdate<=duedate) then yes, and if not, no; then secondarily compare the ontime's (or yes's) to the total number of records returned (yes's and no's) for the "percentage of ontime deliveries".  I hope I'm explaining myself correctly.  Thanks in advance!